# matching words between 2 csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a two csv files and I want to count every word in a row that matches with a word from the second file. For example:

*text.csv*

```
    text                                         number
0   very nice house, and great garden               3
1   the book is very boring                         4
2   it was very interesting final end               5
3   I have no idea which    book do you prefer      4
```

*words.csv*

```
       word              score
0      boring           -1.0
1      very             -1.0
2      interesting       1.0
3      great             1.0
4      book              0.5
```

I want to count the words that matches with the second file and get the following output:

```
[[2,3], [3,4], [2,5], [1,4]]
```

For example, in `[2,3]` is the number of matched words `(very, great)` and
`3` is the number. What I tried is

```
matches=[]
text=df1['text'].str.split()
words=df2['word'].str.split()
for word in text:
    for item in words:
        if word== item:
            matches.append([1,1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to count occurrences of `words` from `df2` in each string of the column `text` in `df1`:

```
counts = df1['text'].str.count(fr"\b({'|'.join(df2['word'])})\b")
matches = list(zip(counts, df1['number']))
```

---

```
>>> matches

[(2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 5), (1, 4)]
```

Comment: Yes, but the only thing is that I get this output [(2, '3'), (3, '4'), (2, '5'), (1, '4')] how can I get it without str?

Comment: @Ellen I guess the `dtype` of your column `number` is `str`. you can simply change the `dtype` before zipping like this: `matches = list(zip(counts, df1['number'].astype(int)))`

Comment: hi @Ellen Saw your recently posted question, i think i might be able to help you out...to discuss you can join [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228691/ds5)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me :-)

`counts = df1['text'].str.count(fr"\b({'|'.join(df2['word'])})\b") convert_df1 = df1.applymap(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore')) matches = list(zip(counts, convert_df1['number']))`